# Login with either email or username with Fortify Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-fortify

I'm trying to allow users to login using either email or username along with their password.

I've added the following code inside boot() in FortifyServiceProvider.php :

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)
            ->orWhere('username', $request->username)
            ->first();

        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        }
    });
```

But now when users try to login by entering their username instead of email they get the following error message:

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've forgotten to change the following line:

```
->orWhere('username', $request->username)
```

To:

```
->orWhere('username', $request->email)
```

Because simply there is only one field in my login form that can hold either email or username. The name of this field is 'email'.

Answer (score 2):

First as in the documentation Customizing User Authentication

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    
            if ($user &&
                Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                return $user;
            }
        });
    
        // ...
    }
```

Filter your request:

```
$username = filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'name';
```

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            $username = filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'name';
            $user = User::where($username, $request->email)
                ->first();
            if (
                $user &&
                Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
            ) {
                return $user;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, this worked well!

For those using Vue.js:

1. Ensure that in Login.vue (resources/js/Pages/Auth/) you change the 'type' attribute of the 'email' input from 'email' to 'text' (`type="text"`), else you'll get a validation error.  Also change the label value to "Username or Email".
2. Ensure 'Register.vue' and 'UpdateProfileInformation.vue' (resources/js/Pages/Profile) has inputs for 'Username' in the template and `username: this.user.username` in the script data form.
3. Ensure 'CreateNewUser.php' and 'UpdateUserProfileInformation.php' (app/Actions/Fortify/) methods include this field (with a 'unique' rule).
4. Ensure the 'User' model has a field 'username' (unique, with associated db migration).